# How to color each letter differently without using spans CSS+HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to render a dna sequence consisting of letters `A`, `C`, `G`, `T`. I want each letter to have a different `background-color`. I tried creating a `<span>` for all of them with different classes based on what letter they are, but that quickly bricks the browser, as I'm trying to read long sequences. (Even with a 1MB file).

Is there any way I can have CSS display a letter with a different `background-color`, depending on the context? Currently, I have a `<table id="dna-content">`, so whenever the string `ACGTACCGGTT` is displayed in it, I want all `A`s to have a red bg, and so on.

**EDIT:** Below is a MRE. The idea would be to load the sequences from a file, and it can contain many and very long sequences, with file sizes reaching up to `100MB`.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            DNA VIEWER
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>

            <table id="dna_content">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Sequence</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`style.css`:

```
.nuc_A {
    background-color: #DC143C;
}

.nuc_C {
    background-color: #7FFF00;
}

.nuc_G {
    background-color: #FFD700;
}

.nuc_T {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
}
```

`script.js`:

```
function display_dna_sequence(name, sequence){
    const content = document.getElementById("dna_content");
    var row = content.insertRow(-1);
    var name_cell = row.insertCell(0);
    name_cell.innerHTML = name;
    var seq_cell = row.insertCell(1);
    for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++){
        var new_span = document.createElement('span');
        new_span.innerHTML = sequence[i];
        new_span.className = "nuc_" + sequence[i];

        seq_cell.appendChild(new_span);
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    display_dna_sequence("name", "ACGTCGTA");
    display_dna_sequence("name2", "ACCCGTGCA");
}
```

Comment: Nope, you will have to manage an amount of tags of screen. You can't really style anything based on `textContent` of shapes of the letters etc... It will soon crash the browser, so you need a different interface where you only need to render a set amount the browser can handle.

Comment: Your approach sounds like a good way to go about it (though with classes rather than IDs) The issue of "bricking the browser" would be better handled by virtualising the content, so not everything is in memory at once (E.g. the majority of offscreen content wouldn't be loaded, and would be created when scrolled into view)

Comment: @DBS ah, that makes sense! I'll look into it!

Comment: Just thinking aloud, haven't tried it, not sure where to start: when you read in the sequence file, why not create an image where each letter read is a colored pixel and use that as a background image. `background-position` would determine start color of a row. One million letters would yield a mere 1000x1000 image. All depends on how you want to display the sequences. As said, my chaotic brain at work. Maybe something along those lines. Post a [reprex] to toy with....

Comment: @RenevanderLende that sounds like a great idea! I guess, because each char is 2 bytes, and each pixel would also be on that order of magnitude in a bitmap, we'd still have the same space complexity. I added an MRE if you want to play with it.

Comment: Suppose 1 row of sequences is 1 row of pixels in an image. Put all sequence rows in a container and *stretch* the image as background of the container. Would be doable, will need a bit solving proper scaling issues. A bit like displaying an image stretched to a convenient size (font wise) and put a grid of characters on top of it. I know little to nothing about DNA, but I guess you could create a (list of) image(s) for each chromosome of an organism. While an image indeed takes up memory, the html would be limited to showing the image. Some kind of big photo gallery.

Comment: @RenevanderLende That makes sense. What I eventually want to do is to have a web/electron app to view sequence files. So I would have to create these bitmaps on the fly, as I load stuff. I'm not sure how to do that except for in a canvas.

Comment: I expect SO will start nagging about going into chat to continue, so I created a SO chat room [Rene DNA](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255736/rene-dna) you can enter if you want to work on this.... I'm in Amsterdam GMT+2, so I might be out in a while.

Comment: How about designing your own, 4 character, color font? (Like an emoji font, it could have color).

Comment: @AHaworth that's a really good idea!